# Android MediaPlayer: getDuration() returns 0 after prepare()

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I'm using MediaPlayer on Honeycomb and cannot get the duration of any HLS (http live streaming) video in the function onPrepared().

If `getDuration()` is called after `prepare()`, it returns 0:

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // getduration returns 0
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Log.d(TAG, "duration: " + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
}
```

However, the videos starts playing.

If `getDuration()` is called in `onVideoSizeChanged()` it returns the correct value,

```
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    // returns the correct value
    Log.d(TAG, "duration: " + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
}
```

Why does `getDuration()` work in `onVideoSizeChanged()` but not in `onPrepared()`?

**Edit**: At first I thought getDuration() doesn't work at all, but found it to return the correct value in onVideoSizeChanged(). Modified question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything you can do about this.  The stream details won't be known until the stream is being read.  Depending on the format there may be correct information near the front of the stream, a hint or nothing.

Since the video size change listener is always called you'll have to restructure your code to get the duration then (if it is available).

(Even if this is a bug and even if it is fixed, such a fix would not be deployed to millions of existing devices so you are stuck with current behaviour.)

Comment: What happend if mp.getDuration() called in a Thread, this thread called each 100ms ? I think to a point time this function return not zero but it not correct. Why ?